# captionof destroys parskip

Tags: captions, parskip

I am using caption of with block paragraphs. Once a caption has been displayed there is no gap between paragraphs. Can anyone help?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skip=-5pt, font=scriptsize]{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}

\newfloat{Snippet}{th}{snippets}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Python,
  basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  tabsize=4
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
        primary_colours = ["red", "blue", "yellow"]
    \end{lstlisting}
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[2]
    \begin{lstlisting}
        primary_colours = ["red", "blue", "yellow"]
    \end{lstlisting}
    \captionof{Snippet}{\texttt{primary\_colours}}
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, you get a message by LaTeX: `\captionof outside box or environment. See the caption package documentation for explanation.`  All changes made by `\captionof` are not *trapped* inside an environment (like `minipage`).

Comment: It is intentional: `\setcaptiontype` used by `\captionof` resets the `\parskip`, `\parindent` and even calls `\sloppy`. So you must use them inside an environment as Johannes wrote. But I don't think that it is a good behaviour to change the typesetting environment in this way. I suggest that you write the author.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it. I'll check that the environment gives what I want

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use option `caption` and `captionpos` for the `lstlisting` environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skip=-5pt, font=scriptsize]{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Python,
  basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  tabsize=4
}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Snippet}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
        primary_colours = ["red", "blue", "yellow"]
    \end{lstlisting}
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[2]
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption={\texttt{primary\_colours}},captionpos=b]
        primary_colours = ["red", "blue", "yellow"]
    \end{lstlisting}
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]